# What is this 作りたて

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from a dialogue between me and my language partner. 
We were talking about food which is prepared in front of the eyes of a customer in the restaurant/hotel. In the following section, I stumbled across the word/form 作りたて and I don't know what this たて is supposed to mean:

日本の場合では、その場で寿司を握ってくれたり、天ぷらを揚げてくれたりします。お客さんは作っている様子を見ることができ、作りたてを食べることができます。

My attempt at translation:
"In case of japan, at this spot, they make sushi and fry tenpura. The customer can see the status of making and  can eat...."

As I said I don't know how to translate this 作りたて so I left it out, although I guess it means something along the lines of "product"?

Comment: Please also see the second definition here: http://jisho.org/word/%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A6